# Why is my background image getting cut off at the bottom?

Tags: css

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html, body{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height: 100vh;
}

body{
    color:white;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    background: url("images/friends.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    position: relative;
}

.container{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;    
}

.container2{
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}

header{
    padding:1em;
    margin: 0;
}

/*navigation styling*/
#navbar{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#navbar ul{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    list-style:none;
}

#navbar ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:.75rem;
}

header nav li a:hover{
    color:red;
    transition:.75s;
}

/*login modal styling*/
#login-modal{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    text-align:center;
    display: none;
}

#login-content{
    height:80%;
    width:25%;
    position:relative;
    background-color:red;
    border-radius:2%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content:center;
    text-align:center;
}

.close{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:5%;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.login-input{
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto 1.5rem auto;
    padding:.5rem;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius:24px;
}

#login-logo{
    height:6rem;
    width:6rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;;
}

.agreement{
    margin:1.5rem 1rem;
}

/*remove border on inputs, etc.*/
input:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus,
button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.button{
    width: 6rem;
    height: 2.5rem;
    color: red;
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:24px;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.button:hover{
    color:white;
    background-color: #861111;
    transition:.75s;
}

a{
    color:white;
}
/*main description of site for homepage*/
.maindescription{
    margin:2rem;
}
.description-header{
    font-size:4rem;
    margin-bottom:.5rem;
}

.description{
    margin-bottom: .75rem;
}

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" 
href="images\free_horizontal_on_white_by_logaster.jpg">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" sizes="32x32" 
href="images\free_horizontal_on_white_by_logaster.jpg">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" sizes="16x16" 
 href="images\free_horizontal_on_white_by_logaster.jpg">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resolve.css">
    <title>Resolve - Real Women, Real Feedback</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <nav id="navbar">
      <div  id="branding">
       <a href="indexresolve.html"><img src="images/lasttry.png" 
                      alt="resolvelogo"></a>
     </div>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="indexresolve.html"Home></a></li>
       <li><a class="current" href="howitworks.html">How It 
                        Works</a></li>
       <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
       <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
<li><button id="login" class="button">Log In</button> 
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
<!-- Login Modal -->
<div id="login-modal">
<div id="login-content">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<div>
<img id="login-logo" 
src="images\free_horizontal_on_white_by_logaster.jpg">
</div>
<form>
<input class ="login-input" type="text" 
placeholder="username" >
<input class ="login-input" type="password" 
placeholder="password">
<button class="button" id="modalbutton">Log 
In</button>
</form>
<p class="agreement">By clicking log in, you agree 
to our <a href="terms.html">Terms</a>, <a href="privacy.html">Privacy 
Policy</a>, and
our <a href="cookie.html">Cookie Policy</a>.</p>
<P><a href="forgotpasswords">Forgot Username or 
Password?</a></P>
</div>
</div>
<!--End Login Modal-->
</nav> 
</header>
<section>
<!--Guys-->
<div class="container2">
<div class="maindescription">
<h1 class="description-header">Guys</h1>
<h2 class="description">Resolve is the new way to improve 
your dating life. Get real women's unbiased feedback on your 
dating profiles, the way you dress, your body language, 
conversational skills, and more. Real, actionable advice on how to become a 
man 
that women will desire.</h2>
<button class="button">Get Started</button>
</div>
<!--Ladies-->
<div class="maindescription">
<h1 class="description-header">Ladies</h1>
<h2 class="description">dhkjfdah jdhfakjh jhafdkjh kjhfdalkjf lkjafhd 
fhkahuf kjeuud eeuiw udhakje huidhf aufhlahfa fuashfeudhfyus fuaifhdsh
khadf alufhaliufhalifhaf sf!  </h2>
<button class="button">Get Started</button>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<script src="resolve.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want my background image to cover 100% of the browser window, I do not care if it is cropped. Right now at a certain size, it cuts off at the bottom. I tried putting the background image in the HTML selector in CSS instead of the body selector but that did not work. Overflow: hidden worked but it cut off the content as well. 
Here is my jsfiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/benmikola66/vu6btxpw/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change body to:

```
body {
    color:white;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/5tJtgDD1/friends.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yd4mk25o/)

Comment: Vendor prefixes for that haven't been needed in any browser for many, many years.